# Java misplaced constructs

Tags: java, construct

I recently installed eclipse on my mac and I was fooling around with it in class. I keep getting misplaced construct errors on my first print line and a bunch on syntax error on my main declaration. I'm not really sure whats up.

```
 import static java.lang.System.out;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public static void main (string args[]) 
  {

double a, b, c, d, e, f;

Scanner input = new Scanner();
out.println(" Please enter the first number: ");
a = imput.nextDouble;
out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
b = imput.nextDouble;
out.println ("Please enter the third number : ");
c = imput.nextDouble;
out.println ("Please enter in fourth number : ");
d = imput.nextDouble;
out.println(" Please enter in fifth number : ");
e = imput.nextDouble; 



double sum = a + b + c + d + e;
```

}

This isn't finished but as far as I can see I have values for all my variables and everything is closed the way it should be.

Comment: You haven't kept it under a  class.

Comment: You have many issues in your code, in my answer, you'll see the full running code, fixes implemented and errors explained.

Comment: You should really follow closer what you're learning in class and/or use a book or tutorial. Java is not a language that can be properly learned by "fooling around"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors in the code:

- no class declaration
- incorrect constructor call for `Scanner` - it doesn't accept empty arguments
- nextDouble should have parenthesis ()
- `imput` should be `input`, as you declared `input`
- string should be String

Here's the corrected code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double a, b, c, d, e, f;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        out.println(" Please enter the first number: ");
        a = input.nextDouble();
        out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
        b = input.nextDouble();
        out.println("Please enter the third number : ");
        c = input.nextDouble();
        out.println("Please enter in fourth number : ");
        d = input.nextDouble();
        out.println(" Please enter in fifth number : ");
        e = input.nextDouble();

        double sum = a + b + c + d + e;
        out.println("Sum is : " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

1. You're need to add class declaration.
2. main parameter is `String` and not string.
3. `imput` should be `input`.

Comment: Wow, I feel pretty dumb. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the class declaration! In Java *everything* must be inside a class. This is very different from C/C++, Python, and a lot of other languages that support *functions* (Java only has *methods*).

E.g., if this is all in a file called *MyTest.java* then:

```
 import static java.lang.System.out;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class MyTest {

   public static void main (string args[]) 
    {

  double a, b, c, d, e, f;

  Scanner input = new Scanner();
  out.println(" Please enter the first number: ");
  a = imput.nextDouble;
  out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
  b = imput.nextDouble;
  out.println ("Please enter the third number : ");
  c = imput.nextDouble;
  out.println ("Please enter in fourth number : ");
  d = imput.nextDouble;
  out.println(" Please enter in fifth number : ");
  e = imput.nextDouble; 



  double sum = a + b + c + d + e;
  }
 }
```

Comment: There are several other minor issues remaining in the code, but the class definition fixes the specific error you mentioned. See @baraky's answer for more issues.